# Send message over bluetooth with Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, bluetooth, arduino, pybluez

I am currently trying to send a message from Python 3 to a Arduino (with HC-06). I've managed to establish a connection but I can't seem to find the right way to send a message.

Here is the code I use to setup the connection (I'm using PyBluez for bluetooth):

```
import sys
import bluetooth

bd_addr = '[MAC-address for HC-06]'
port = 1
sock = bluetooth.BluetoothSocket(bluetooth.RFCOMM)
sock.connect((bd_addr,port))
```

To send I'm trying:

```
sock.send("2")
```

Which throws the error: "TypeError: Expecting byte-buffer, got str".

Also tried:

```
sock.send(str('2'))
```

It also throws an error: "TypeError: Expecting byte-buffer, got str".

I've tried a bunch of other like "sock.send(2)", "sock.send(b'2')", bytearray, "sock.send(bytes(["2"]))". Basicly, whatever datatype I'm trying to send it demands another.

I've managed to send all my commands (only 1 and 2 at the moment) via a Bluetooth-terminal on my Android phone so there is no problem on the Arduino site.

There is a lot of guides out there with examples that I'm not able to replicate. Can anyone please tell me how I send basic commands? Am I even close to the answer?

**EDIT:**
I've now tried "sock.send("2".encode())" and it also throws an error: "TypeError: data must be string, was class 'bytes'"

Using another ide gave me more specific information about the errors:

**sock.send("2"):**
Warning (from warnings module):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/PyBluez-0.22-py3.6.egg/lightblue/_bluetoothsockets.py", line 737
    Foundation.NSData.alloc().initWithBytes_length_(data, len(data)),
UninitializedDeallocWarning: leaking an uninitialized object of type _NSPlaceholderData
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "", line 1, in 
    sock.send("2")
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/PyBluez-0.22-py3.6.egg/bluetooth/osx.py", line 122, in send
    return self._sock.send(data)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/PyBluez-0.22-py3.6.egg/lightblue/_bluetoothsockets.py", line 524, in send
    result = self.__conn.write(writebuf[:sendbytecount])
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/PyBluez-0.22-py3.6.egg/lightblue/_bluetoothsockets.py", line 737, in write
    Foundation.NSData.alloc().initWithBytes_length_(data, len(data)),
TypeError: Expecting byte-buffer, got str

**sock.send("2".encode()):**
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "", line 1, in 
    sock.send("2".encode())
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/PyBluez-0.22-py3.6.egg/bluetooth/osx.py", line 122, in send
    return self._sock.send(data)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/PyBluez-0.22-py3.6.egg/lightblue/_bluetoothsockets.py", line 487, in send
    raise TypeError("data must be string, was %s" % type(data))
TypeError: data must be string, was class 'bytes'

I am starting to doubt the library. It's totally possible that I managed to do something wrong when installing PyBluez. I'm gonna see if it might work on my Raspberry Pi 3.

Comment: This is using the bluez library right?

Comment: try using `sock.send('2'.encode())`

Comment: @cunnniemm I'm quiet sure it's PyBluez.

Comment: @ClockSlave Thanks for the tip. Unfortunately it did not work. (Updated original post)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Solution**

When you send data over a socket you have to encode it or its gonna throw a byte buffer error. When you send data over the socket just use.

```
sock.send("2".encode())
```

Comment: Thanks for the idea. Unfortunately it did not work. Updated the original post with more info about the errors.

Comment: @CarlBratt See that is weird though, I tried to do this on my laptop with blue tooth and this worked fine! Ill look into it more.

Comment: Then it's most likley a problem om my part. What system are you running?

Comment: @CarlBratt I tried on ubuntu and windows! Just hat to change the code a little for windows but it still worked for me!

Comment: I've now successfully managed to run it on a Raspberry pi 3, thanks for the help!